# How to reuse Specflow steps from a CodedUITest project in different solution

Tags: coded-ui-tests, specflow

We have Specflow layer on top of our CodedUITest project. We have some common steps in one CodedUITest project(CodedUITestProject1), which we want to use in another CodedUITest project (CodedUITestProejct2) in different solution.

We have created dll of the CodedUITestProject1 and added its reference in CodedUITestProejct2. Also updated the CodedUITestProject2's App.config file to use bindings from External Assembly like this, but is not working. Any thoughts on this.

```
<specFlow>
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
  <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config --><unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
  <plugins>
  <add name="CodedUi" type="Generator" path="." />
  </plugins>
<stepAssemblies>
    <stepAssembly assembly="CodedUITestProject1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </stepAssemblies>

  </specFlow>
```

Comment: What is not working? Please add an error message to your question.

Comment: I am not getting the steps from CodedUITestProject1 in CodedUITestProject2 feature file.  I have created a Specflow steps file in CodedUITestProejct2 and added CodedUITestProejct1 reference in it. And then added a feature file in CodedUITestProject2, and tried create a scenario using the steps from CodedUITestProejct1, but I am not getting the steps from CodedUITestProject1 in CodedUITestProejct2 feature file

Comment: Do you mean the intellisense or when you execute the scenarios?

Comment: Yes the intellisense

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Integration has some bugs when it comes to additional step assemblies. 
So syntax highlighting, IntelliSense and "Go To Definition" can sometimes not work.
Try to delete the specflow-stepmap* files from %temp%.

There are no problems at runtime.

Comment: Now I can add the steps from CodedUITestProject1 in CodedUITestProject2 feature file. But when I press F12 on the step added from CodedUITestProject1 , its not taking to its binding. Also when I run the test I am getting following error

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CodedUITestProject1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. 
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes VS decides on its own to not copy the referenced DLL if no code usages are done in the consuming project. 
`Double check your bin folder for CodedUITestProject1.dll` it should be missing if VS has decided that you don't need it.

If this is the case then you may need to create a dummy instance of a type from CodedUITestProject1.dll in your hooks (or anywhere in the code) so VS can see that you are using something from `CodedUITestProject1.dll`. Once the project is built then you may remove the dummy code you have entered.

Another option could be just to References -> `CodedUITestProject1` -> Properties-> Set `copy local` to `True`. (not confirmed its fixing the problem).

Note: When using BDD steps from external DLL navigation (F12 on a step) is not working.